Spatial correlation with logarithmic binning python
i have a dataframe with one column the total cases of each municipality in Brazil, I have the shapefiles of them too. I'd like to plot the spatial correlation between the number of dengue cases in function of r, like the figure below.

Notice in the plot above the points are closely each other. I can't reproduce this behavior.
This is an example what i tried
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils import locate_ibge_shape_file


# Data
municipios = gpd.read_file(locate_ibge_shape_file())
municipios['ID_MUNICIP'] = municipios['CD_MUN'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1]).astype('int')
dados_2019 = pd.read_csv('dados_2019.csv', usecols=['ID_MUNICIP','Total'])
dados_merged = municipios.merge(dados_2019, left_on='ID_MUNICIP', right_on='ID_MUNICIP', how='outer').fillna(0)

# The convert to CRS
dfp = dados_merged.to_crs("EPSG:3395")

# Distance matrix
coords = np.array([(polygon.centroid.x, polygon.centroid.y) for polygon in dfp.geometry])
distances = distance_matrix(coords, coords)

# 'Log binning' 
min_dist = np.min(distances[distances > 0])  
max_dist = np.max(distances)
num_bins = 50  
bins = np.logspace(np.log10(min_dist), np.log10(max_dist), num=num_bins)

avg_correlations = []
for i in range(len(bins) - 1):
    lower_bound = bins[i]
    upper_bound = bins[i + 1]
    mask = (distances > lower_bound) & (distances <= upper_bound)
    
    gdp_values_1 = [dfp['Total'][i] for i in range(len(dfp)) for j in range(len(dfp)) if mask[i, j]]
    gdp_values_2 = [dfp['Total'][j] for i in range(len(dfp)) for j in range(len(dfp)) if mask[i, j]]
    
    
    if len(gdp_values_1) > 0:
        correlation = pearsonr(gdp_values_1, gdp_values_2)[0]
        avg_correlations.append(correlation)
    else:
        avg_correlations.append(np.nan)


# DataFrame
dfCorr = pd.DataFrame({
    'D_Lag': bins[:-1],  
    'AvCorr': avg_correlations
})

# Plot
plt.plot(dfCorr.D_Lag, dfCorr.AvCorr, 'o')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Distância (log)')
plt.ylabel('Correlação (log)')
plt.title('Correlação Espacial com Binagem Logarítmica')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()



What can I do now? I'm really lost right now.
